# NSXMLParser self signed certificate

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl, nsxmlparser, self-signed

I want to use NSXMLParser to load XML from site which has self signed certificate. I have tried doing it using this code:

```
posts = []
parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string:"https://site.site.net/?my_xml"))!)!
parser.delegate = self
parser.parse()
```

However contentsOfURL method doesnt work with self signed certificate. Is there a way to bypass this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Get the XML content with NSURLSession (or Alamofire or else) then pass it to the parser.

Comment: I will probably try alamofire, thanks